# Add select rule for dropdown in shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, drop-downs

How to make drop down required if not selected echo a message that says, "please select one option". i have attached screenshot to explain further the question i'm asking.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this works for me,

Create checkout_index_index.xml in view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Prac_AnsWer/js/view/customjs</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

then create vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/web/js/view/customjs.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Prac_AnsWer/customtemp'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            return this;
        },
    });});
```

and last create template file in vendor/module/view/frontend/web/template/customtemp.html

```
<form action="">
    <label for="custom">Select:</label>
    <select name="custom" id="custom" required>
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="volvo">Option 1</option>
        <option value="saab">Option 2</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Option 3</option>
        <option value="audi">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kIP6.png

Comment: doesn't look like it validate if you didn't pick anything on dropdown